# How can this be correct, because it is from a native english movie: "I am a strong as a boy" (yes you read it right, not "as strong as")

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction, articles, idiomatic-language

This is from a native english movie [Practice Speaking English](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1puk6bREVMI)  (minute/seconds: 14:10)

A woman and a girl is talking and the girl says the following:

**"I am a strong as a boy, and I prefer to be outdoors instead of cooped up in a kitchen."**

I thought she says **"....as strong as ...."** but she is not. And I checked the subtitles, and the subtitles say **"...a strong as ...".**

So, I thought it must be something different. I checked the dictionary and look up **"strong"** to see if it has a noun form so that **"A STRONG"** could be used, but there seems to be not any noun form of it.

So why does **"a strong"** mean? Is it another way of saying **"I am as strong as a boy."**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is apparently based on an error in an auto-generated transcription, and there is not actual issue with English grammar or usage.

Answer (score 4):

When spoken quickly "as strong" might sound similar to "a strong", but that doesn't mean she said "a strong". This is just a typo in the subtitles. The phrase is "as strong as".

Comment: Yes, definitely just a typo.

Comment: The subtitles even say "English (auto-generated)".

Comment: @Laurel, Not it is not autogenerated. It seems to have been written in big letters. And the subtitles are even shown even if the subtitles of the video are "off".